# Multiple Jquery in single web page

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a web project with following Jquery's first one for Fancybox and the second one for Jquery UI Tabs, but only one is working at a time, I have to comment out one Jquery then one is working. I need both JQ to work to gather. Can any one help me plz. I saw a solution in StackOverflow but it's not working.

**solution form Stackoverflow is**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

**Then, instead of $('#selector').function();, you'd do jQuery_1_3_2('#selector').function(); or jQuery_1_1_3('#selector').function();.**

My jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JSS/fancybox/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="JSS/fancybox/jquery-1.4.3.min.js "><\/script>');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JSS/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JSS/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JSS/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#various1").fancybox({
            maxWidth: 900,
            closeEffect: 'none',
            'showCloseButton': false,
        });
    });
</script>

<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT" SRC="JSS/JQ/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT" SRC="JSS/JQ/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seriously, to use multiple versions of jQuery in a single page, you must have a REALLY good excuse. What you described is not one of them. Just use the latest versions which depend on a common jQuery version.

Comment: Just put the latest one on top.

Comment: I was just about to say the same as @VahurRoosimaa.

Comment: @user1138698 : dear i didnt get why u post my qus negative .as i give the sol. if you dont like its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before too.  I think what I did was to download the most recent version of jquery [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) and select all the components that you need supported, or the whole thing and include just one

When you say comment out jquery's are you referring to the jquery source, or the plugin?  I suppose the plugins could be conflicting in some way.

Good luck.

**EDIT**:  The order you have them in the script may have an effect as well.

Answer (score 0):

use common jQuery version for that

note: this is only a suggestion not deal with this issue(i just suggested you can use xml to maintain the multiple jquery instead to maintain in all pages and refer it in your sitemaster)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use two versions of jQuery doesn't work because you can't "inject" the references `jQuery_1_1_3`, etc. into the frameworks; they will use `$` all over the place which will be wrong for one of them.

You have these options:

1. Find something that does the same as fancybox; there are thousands of frameworks out there, it should be pretty simple to find a replacement.
2. Find a version of fancybox that works with a current release of jQuery
3. Upgrade fancybox for the latest version of jQuery, making a lot of people all over the world happy (if you share your work, that is).
4. Use an older version of UI tabs that works with the ancient jQuery version that fancybox requires. Or find a different framework that does what you want.
5. Downgrade UI tabs to work with the ancient version of jQuery used by fancybox.

Try them in this order.